# Which was the comic where a kid mistakenly called Deadpool Spider-Man?

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, spider-man, deadpool

I saw a panel where a kid goes up to Deadpool and thinks he's Spider-Man and then Deadpool just pretends to be Spider-Man for the kid.

Does anyone know which comic book that is from?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're referring to this panel from [Thunderbolts Vol 2. #15](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/46535/thunderbolts_2012_15).

[image]

Comment: Any idea what the movie he's referring to is?

Comment: @User568458 - Spider-Man 2 (Raimi), presumably. Spider-Man's web stops working.